# Comparing the entities of lists of tuples, find the pair and output their IDs from another list of tuples if they are not the same

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists of tuples as follows:

```
a= [(0.37239153400387603, 0.17091178239454413, 
     0.41009763328456317, 0.7121861651366165), 
    (0.4654894175048452, 0.21363972799318015, 
     0.17091178239454413, 0.37239153400387603, 
     0.7121861651366165)]

b= [(199, 200, 201, 202), 
    (79, 80,200, 199,788)]
```

The first list a has the floating numbers and the second has the integers which are essentially the IDs of the elements of tuples of list a . The  size of the tuples can be variable and not always 4 or 5.

The corresponding tuples in each list have the same size.

The issue is to compare the entities of tuples in list `a` with other entities in tuples of list `a` and check if they are equal. There can be multiple tuples, hundreds of them. Each tuple has to be compared with other tuples and multiple instance of couple ID could be expected and all need to be output if the IDs are unique!

If they are equal and their IDs are not the same, then the pair of IDs needs to be output from the tuples from list b. There can be multiple occurrences of the couples and all need to be output not the first one. The only condition is the uniqueness of the IDs

Output:

```
The lengths of ID 199 and 200 are same in both tuples but we do not output them. 
However, 202 and 788 are output because they have the same length but different IDs.
```

What I used:

```
res = []

for i in xrange(len(a) - 1):
 for j in xrange(i + 1, len(a)):
  if len(a[i] & a[j]) >= 2:
   res.append([index, i, j])
   index += 1
print res
```

but getting some error related to operand not avialable for tuples! Anz suggetions? 
regards

Comment: forgot to add ID description on the edit sorry

Comment: you should add the fact that by IDs what you mean are the values in the list of tubles b

Comment: and 199 and 200 have different IDs no?

Comment: 199 and 200 exist in both tuples

Comment: exactly, not the location of the ID is important but the ID itself. Although the lengths are same for 199 and 200 but since there are same ID so no output is required! but for 202 and 788 the lengths are same so they should be output.

Comment: I have a few questions: 1) is there any relation between a and b? in your code you only use a. 2) are there always 2 tuples in a list or can there be more? If there can be more, you want to compare each tuple with every other tuple? 3) You only want to compare the tuples if they have the same length, right? 4) You want to print all numbers that exist in only one of the 2 tuples that you compare, correct? -- might have more questions but that depends on the answers.

Comment: Now i am officially confused :S

Comment: There can be multiple tuples, hundreds of them. Each tuple has to be compared with other tuples and multiple instance of couple ID could be expected and all need to be output if the IDs are unique!

Comment: im sorry but im lost, what do you mean by ID?

Comment: ID is the number like 199, 200 .. the integer at the corresponding position of the matching entities! in list b

Comment: and the length is therefore the length of the tuple? so where does length come into play?

Comment: because you say 190 and 200 have same length, is that relevant to the output?

Comment: The corresponding floating numbers are same! It is not relevant to output but for clarity actually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I understood correctly all you need is to concatenate corresponding "IDs" to the floating point, then all you would need is:

```
concatenatedList = [ (a[i][j], b[i][j]) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a[i])) ]
for k in range(len(concatenatedList)):
    for l in range(k+1, len(concatenatedList)):
        if concatenatedList[k][0] == concatenatedList[l][0]:
            print("Float number is equal.\n")
            if concatenatedList[k][1] != concatenatedList[l][1]:
                print("IDs are different:\n")
                print(concatenatedList[k][1], concatenatedList[l][1], "\n\n")
            else:
                print("IDs are the same.\n\n")
```

Comment: There is some sort of syntax error:                                                          'print (concatenatedList[k][1], concatenatedList[l][1], "\n\n")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: oops!
missing bracket on print sorry haha

Comment: That should do it i think

Comment: I corrected it already and the new error is :                                                 'else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: the missing bracket was at `print("IDs are different:\n")`

Comment: I have different indentation style but corrected it! thanks.